# Can't find "My Preview Apps" in Oculus Go

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, oculusgo

I'm working on an **Oculus Go** app and haven't figured out yet how to sent it to our test users. The app is not published  to Store yet and we'd like to test on a dozen distributed headsets before publishing. So we uploaded a build to the Alpha channel, added a few people, and invitations were accepted. Everything should have work, but no one can find the app nor "My Preview Apps" section.

Seems like I missed something. I tried Developer Mode, dug into both Oculus Go and Oculus mobile app, w/o any success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"My Preview Apps" will be visible at the end of the "Store" page in the Oculus mobile app.

Comment: Also in the Go headset under 1) Store > Spotlight > scroll to bottom My Preview Apps and 2) Library > Not Installed